# Read string from another process memory address

Tags: c#, .net, memory-address

I have bad information about pc addressing and also i think im making something wrong with my code so it cant find sertain information that i need from address.

i used google and found a method to read string from memory address.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
```

```
class Program
    {
        const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(10828);
            IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[24]; //'Hello World!' takes 12*2 bytes because of Unicode 

            // 0x0046A3B8 is the address where I found the string, replace it with what you found
            ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x00C716EC, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer) + " (" + bytesRead.ToString() + "bytes)");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

ill now explain you what i want and what is my problem
there is an application running name gta-sa.exe
its online gaming and it has textdraw to show some string in screen of game 
i used cheat engine to find address of that string which is showing 
the cheat engine iformation are blow
process 000036F4-gta_sa.exe
Address     Value
00C716EC    NickName

as you can see

```
ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x00C716EC, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
```

i used `0x00C716EC` as address but it shows wierd info like ???? in consol ! how can i get that NickName string ? can you please tell me and help me to understand my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

To read a null terminated wide string from memory you can use this function

```
public static string ReadNullTerminatedWString(IntPtr handle, IntPtr addr, int maxlength)
{
    var bytearray = new byte[maxlength*2];

    IntPtr bytesread = IntPtr.Zero;

    ReadProcessMemory(handle, addr, bytearray, maxlength*2, out bytesread);

    int nullterm = 0;
    while (nullterm < bytesread.ToInt64() && bytearray[nullterm] != 0)
    {
        nullterm = nullterm + 2;
    }

    string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytearray, 0, nullterm);

    return s;
}
```

You must run as admin, you must compile for the same bitness as the target process.  If the target is x86, compile for x86.